# Validation Checklist Passing Score

Tags: survey, validity

I have a mixed-method thesis ongoing. I'm currently on the validation stage of my survey and interview questions. I have adopted a validation checklist from the internet composing of 15 items with a 4-point rating key (Strongly Agree as 4; Agree as 3; Disagree as 2; Strongly Disagree as 1). My thesis advisor told me to have a passing score in the checklist to determine whether the checklist is validated enough and can be deployed to the respondents. However, I can't seem to find any reference in the internet of the passing score for a validation checklist.

I was wondering if I can just take the mean of the scores of the 15-items, then align it with my rating key. For example, a mean of 3.15 means "Agree"; 2.55 means "Disagree". So, if I were to base it here, then the passing score would be 3.00 since it is the minimum point of "Agree".

Is this okay? Or do you have any suggestions regarding how could I state the passing score for the validation checklist? Note that no item in the checklist is weighted (e.g. x2 or x3).

Your suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is "passing score" and what is the point of obtaining it? I.e. what does it say about the survey or its validity? I have never heard of this kind of validation process for a survey and I have conducted a fair amount of survey research (though only within a specific field).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, it's not OK.

Longer answer: If the checklist doesn't have any information on its own scoring and validity, then I would be leery of using it at all. However, you certainly can't just use the mean. Depending on what the items are in the checklist, a single "disagree" or "strongly disagree" could mean it's not good.

In fact, I disagree with your advisor. Unless I am misunderstanding you, or you are misunderstanding him, then setting a score for "pass" and "valid enough" is not a good idea.

Validity is a complex concept, with many facets (e.g. face validity, construct validity, content validity). Fully validating a questionnaire takes weeks, or even longer, and involve many people. That isn't always done, of course, but it gives you an idea of why it can't be reduced to a single score with a pass/fail criterion.

You *might* want to say "any disagree or strongly disagree means it's invalid" but that's iffy, even if the items are good.

Also, you say you found this "on the internet".  While some very good things can be found on the internet, so can a lot of garbage. Where did you find it? Who wrote it? What are their qualifications?